# Is there a max trainer level in Magikarp Jump?

Tags: magikarp-jump

**Is there a maximum trainer level in Magikarp Jump?**

I keep gaining exp, but there's no indicator for how much exp is needed for each level, or whether there is a max level.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. It's a simple and valid question, and even has a good answer (better than what I expected).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple question, simple answer: **yes**.

The maximum Trainer Level is currently 79. It tends to increase whenever there's a major game patch.

A full list of levels, as well as EXP needed to reach them, can be found on [Serebii](http://www.serebii.net/magikarpjump/trainerrank.shtml).

```
Rank        Exp Required    Max. Magikarp Level

Rank 1      0               Lv. 11
Rank 2      2               Lv. 12
Rank 3      9               Lv. 13
Rank 4      18              Lv. 14
Rank 5      29              Lv. 15
Rank 6      43              Lv. 16
Rank 7      58              Lv. 17
Rank 8      75              Lv. 18
Rank 9      96              Lv. 19
Rank 10     121             Lv. 20
Rank 11     151             Lv. 21
Rank 12     188             Lv. 22
Rank 13     233             Lv. 23
Rank 14     289             Lv. 24
Rank 15     352             Lv. 25
Rank 16     423             Lv. 26
Rank 17     503             Lv. 27
Rank 18     599             Lv. 28
Rank 19     714             Lv. 29
Rank 20     852             Lv. 30
Rank 21     1,022           Lv. 31
Rank 22     1,231           Lv. 32
Rank 23     1,489           Lv. 33
Rank 24     1,780           Lv. 34
Rank 25     2,108           Lv. 35
Rank 26     2,478           Lv. 36
Rank 27     2,922           Lv. 37
Rank 28     3,454           Lv. 38
Rank 29     4,093           Lv. 39
Rank 30     4,879           Lv. 40
Rank 31     5,846           Lv. 41
Rank 32     7,035           Lv. 42
Rank 33     8,376           Lv. 43
Rank 34     9,889           Lv. 44
Rank 35     11,596          Lv. 45
Rank 36     13,644          Lv. 46
Rank 37     16,101          Lv. 47
Rank 38     19,050          Lv. 48
Rank 39     22,677          Lv. 49
Rank 40     27,139          Lv. 50
Rank 41     32,627          Lv. 51
Rank 42     39,487          Lv. 52
Rank 43     48,061          Lv. 53
Rank 44     58,779          Lv. 54
Rank 45     70,869          Lv. 55
Rank 46     84,507          Lv. 56
Rank 47     99,890          Lv. 57
Rank 48     118,350         Lv. 58
Rank 49     140,502         Lv. 59
Rank 50     167,084         Lv. 60
Rank 51     199,780         Lv. 61
Rank 52     239,996         Lv. 62
Rank 53     289,462         Lv. 63
Rank 54     351,294         Lv. 64
Rank 55     428,584         Lv. 65
Rank 56     525,197         Lv. 66
Rank 57     634,176         Lv. 67
Rank 58     757,104         Lv. 68
Rank 59     895,767         Lv. 69
Rank 60     1,062,163       Lv. 70
Rank 61     1,261,838       Lv. 71
Rank 62     1,501,448       Lv. 72
Rank 63     1,796,168       Lv. 73
Rank 64     2,158,674       Lv. 74
Rank 65     2,604,556       Lv. 75
Rank 66     3,161,909       Lv. 76
Rank 67     3,858,600       Lv. 77
Rank 68     4,729,464       Lv. 78
Rank 69     5,711,798       Lv. 79
Rank 70     6,819,871       Lv. 80
Rank 71     8,069,777       Lv. 81
Rank 72     9,569,664       Lv. 82
Rank 73     11,369,529      Lv. 83
Rank 74     13,529,367      Lv. 84
Rank 75     16,185,968      Lv. 85
Rank 76     19,453,587      Lv. 86
Rank 77     23,472,758      Lv. 87
Rank 78     28,496,722      Lv. 88
Rank 79     34,776,677      Lv. 89
```

Comment: The latest update adds up to Rank 100!

Answer (score -1):

[image]

This is the max level you you will get the bonbon and not more do point

Comment: Absol's answer contains a full EXP chart for trainer levels. I'm not sure what this answer adds.